# Wordpress and Code Igniter integration for CMS-Blog project

Tags: php, wordpress, codeigniter

I'm working on a Restaurant website project and my client wants a Blog section and a complex Reservation System with it.

I use Wordpress to work with blogs and I prefer to use Code Igniter for systems but I don't know if these two can work good together. I have been reading some articles regarding the integration of CI to WP and a lot of it points out that conflicts are inevitable when doing so.

Are there any solutions you can offer me? One that is easy to integrate, no conflicts and helps me keep my code DRY.

Comment: Setup codeigniter/Wordpress  in this structure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you pointed out, integration is not readily available. If you truly wanted to integrate them, it would be a long road (and not likely worth it).  One think you could do is install them separately and just link between the two when necessary (not ideal, but doable). For instance you could install CodeIgniter at `example.com/reservations/`, and then install your blog at `example.com/blog/`

You could also utilize subdomains if you wanted.  I honestly would go this route if I was faced with the same situation...I definitely would not waste the time in trying to integrate the two if there isn't a lot need (ie, blog posts needing to access information in the reservation system, etc...).